# Proof about infinite sum

Tags: limits, binary

Define recursively-defined function $f_x:N\to\{{0,1\}}^N$ where x belongs to [0,1):

For $n=1$,$f_x(1)=0$ if $x$ belongs to $[0,1/2)$, $a_1=0$, $b_1=1/2$ in this case;

$f_x(1)=1$ if $x$ belongs to $[1/2,1)$, $a_1=1/2$, $b_1=1$ in this case.

For $n\ge2$, $f_x(n)=0$ if $x$ belongs to $[a_{n-1},(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})/2)$, in this case, $a_n=a_{n-1}$, $b_n=(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})/2$;

$f_x(n)=1$ if $x$ belongs to $[(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})/2,b_{n-1})$, in this case $a_n=(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})/2$, $b_n=b_{n-1}$.

How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_x(n)/2^n=x$?

I think to let epsilon equals to $1/2^n$ is a possible way but I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I have attempted to reformat, but I left the original in there in case I got things badly wrong. It's not clear whether to render fx as $fx$ or $f_x$ or $f(x)$ or ...? Oh, and someone should remove the set-theory tag, before Asaf sees it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the editing. It should be f_x.

Comment: I might be missing something...but what are $a_n$ and $b_n$? I understand they are defined recursively, but this depends on $x$. I don't get it.

Comment: @julien, I think $a_1$ and $b_1$ are defined by lines 2 and 3; then the other $a_i$ and $b_i$ are being defined recursively in lines 4 and 5. I think.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So for each $x$ (in $[0,1)$ I guess), we define a function $f_x$ and two sequences $a_n,b_n$. I see, it makes sense.

Comment: Your function $f_x$ is not defined on $[0,1)$. It is defined on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Gerry: I already saw it, the wonders of smartphones; but I wasn't inclined to change anything, the wonders of hangovers.

Comment: @Asaf, still celebrating Purim?

Comment: @Gerry: No, refill night. First beer for a relatively steep price, all the next beers for a ridiculous price. I actually have no idea as for why am I awake at this hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What $f_x$ computes is the binary expansion of $x$, ie
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{f_x(n)}{2^n}=x.
$$

The sequences $a_n,b_n$ are constructed in such a way that
$$
x\in [a_n,b_n)
$$
for all $n$.

These are dyadic numbers. And we go down the binary tree of dyadic numbers as $n$ grows.

We can easily prove by induction that 
$$
b_n-a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}.
$$

At step $n$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f_x(k)}{2^k}=a_n\leq x <b_n.
$$
The inequalities follow from the construction and have already been observed.
Now for the lhs equality, we will use induction.

This indeed true for $n=1$.
Now assume it is true for $n-1$.
Case 1: $f_x(n)=0$ then $a_n=a_{n-1}$ and you add zero to the partial sum so it remains equal to $a_n$.
Case 2: $f_x(n)=1$ then
$$
a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}{2}=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}+1/2^{n-1}}{2}=a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2^n}.
$$
And $1/2^n$ is exactly what you add to the partial sum in this case. So it remains equal to $a_n$.
This completes the induction.

So $a_n$ is nondecreasing bounded above by $x$, $b_n$ is nonincreasing bounded below by $x$, and $b_n-a_n$ tends to $0$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} b_n=x.
$$

The result follows.

Comment: That's true. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_x(n)/2^n=a_n at step n?

Comment: I mean$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f_x(k)}{2^k}=a_n
$$

Comment: @user64030 I'll add some details. Done, see the edit.